# Is it necessary to convert a data to binary set to calculate similarity (jaccard index)?

Tags: r, dataframe, binary-data

I need to calculate jaccard similarity to dataframe below:

```
df = data.frame(
    a=c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4"), 
    b=c("100", "101", "111", "25841", "111", "101", "106", "101", "108", "100", "30256", "108", "112"))
```

Is necessary i convert data to binary set? How do this?

```
  100 101 111 25841 106 108 30256 112
1  1   1   1   1     0   0    0    0
2  0   1   1   0     1   0    0    0
3  0   1   0   0     0   1    0    0
4  1   0   0   0     0   1    1    1
```

And use jaccard <- vegdist(df, method = "jaccard")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jaccard index can be derived from binary table. See this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) article.

Here, I am showing another way to get jaccard index.

```
# Data
df = data.frame(
  a=c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4"), 
  b=c("100", "101", "111", "25841", "111", "101", "106", "101", "108", "100", "30256", "108", "112"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library('data.table')
setDT(df)

# jaccard index
jaccard_index <- function(x,y)
{
  x_int <- intersect(x,y)  # xny
  x_union <- union(x,y)    # xuy
  return( length(x_int)/length(x_union))
}

ji <- combn(unique(df$a), 2, FUN = function(z){
  x <- df[ a %in% z[1], b]
  y <- df[ a %in% z[2], b]
  jaccard_index(x,y)
  })
ji <- setNames( ji, combn(unique(df$a), 2, FUN = paste0, collapse = ""))
ji
#        12        13        14        23        24        34 
# 0.4000000 0.2000000 0.1428571 0.2500000 0.0000000 0.2000000 
# jaccard distance
jd <- 1- ji
jd
#        12        13        14        23        24        34 
# 0.6000000 0.8000000 0.8571429 0.7500000 1.0000000 0.8000000
```

Using test data from examples [here](http://www.statisticshowto.com/jaccard-index/). It also shows expected output as a point of reference:

```
# test data
test <- data.frame( a = c(rep("A",5), rep("B", 7)),
                    b = c(0,1,2,5,6,0,2,3,4,5,7,9),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
setDT(test)

# jaccard index
ji_test <- combn(unique(test$a), 2, FUN = function(z){
  x <- test[ a %in% z[1], b]
  y <- test[ a %in% z[2], b]
  jaccard_index(x,y)
})
ji_test <- setNames( ji_test, combn(unique(test$a), 2, FUN = paste0, collapse = ""))
ji_test
# AB 
# 0.3333333 

# jaccard distance
jd_test <- 1- ji_test
jd_test
# AB 
# 0.6666667
```

Comment: Thanks @Sathish. I know that Jaccard similarity coefficient is a used for comparing the similarity of sample sets. I need to do an overlapping analysis. When calculate ji_test and jd_test, we are finding the correlation between the groups. Would you have suggestions on how to calculate overlapping?

Comment: `ji_test` refers to similarity and `jd_test` refers to dissimilarity. They are complement of each other. Please post a separate question on what you mean by "calculate overlapping". Please explain what you tried. It will help us understand your coding problem.